# Loopback where filter in child relation with pagination

Tags: pagination, nested, where-clause, relation, loopback

```
-------------------
Schema Notification
-------------------
id,
userId,
status,
...


-----------
Schema User
-----------
id
name
email
...
```

I have a model named `Notification` in loopback, which roughly has 
id, userId, ..... and some other fields. Here userId is a relation to `user` table which has `name` and other details of user.

**`What I have:`**
At the front end, I have displayed all these notifications in a paginated form (10 records per page).
Front-end View:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| UserName  UserEmail   NotificationStatus | 
+------------------------------------------+
| xxxx      xxx@xx.xxx  PENDING            |
| xxxx      xxx@xx.xxx  ACCEPTED           |
| xxxx      xxx@xx.xxx  REJECTED           |
--------------------------------------------
```

**`What I want:`**
To be able search through the notifications based on name in the user relation.

**`What I already know:`**
is that loopback already provides something like:

```
include: [{
  relation:"user" ,
  scope:{ 
    where:{
      name: { like: 'name-of-user', options: 'i'} 
    }
  }
}]
```

**`What It returns:`**
is all the notifications but only include users that has name matching with the string I passed. i.e. prints all the notifications, but leaves the user names  and email that are not matching with the string I passed.

**`What I thought to try:`**
is to remove the entries in my angular front-end controller, which do not have user Object just before assigning the http response to a scope variable which loops through entries in html. But let's say if 5 out of 10 entries will not have users, angular will splice out those entries but actually there must be 10 entries per page unless there are no records matching the criteria.

I hope I made sense in question, and seek for some solution on the matter.
Thanks

Comment: I think that's because ORM include works like left join. when there is no value to include, it returns null value. so to make it work, you need to use user model and include Notification

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of now with loopback if you are using rdbms type of schema . 
Look at some open issues .

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517 https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/683

> you might need to look for native sql for this issues

Comment: I believe you are right @rahul. I have now modified the code and built custom mongodb aggregations to achieve the same.